# How to parallelize this function for faster performance

Tags: python, numpy, cuda, numba

I have a function like `fun1` and it is called million times. I want to parallelize `fun1` for faster execution time, may be using `@cuda.jit` or similar method. I tried using `@njit` and found that execution is more than running without it. Can someone suggest an efficient way?

```
import numpy as np
from numba import njit
import time

@njit
def fun1(n1, b):
    i1 = 0
    while n1 > b[i1][0]:
        i1 += 1
    
    n2 = b[i1-2][1]*b[i1-2][0] + b[i1-1][1]* b[i1-1][0] + \
    b[i1][1]*b[i1][0] + b[i1+1][1]/b[i1-1][0] + b[i1+2][1]/b[i1+2][0]
    
    return n2
    
a = np.random.random((5000,2))
a[:,0] = a[:,0] * 100
b = a[a[:, 0].argsort()]
n1 = 40.0

start_time = time.time()
print("Answer = {}".format(fun1(n1,b)))
print("Runtime = {} s".format(time.time() - start_time))
```

Answer (score 2):

The function `fun1` alone cannot be parallelized (at least not without additional assumption not provided in the question) since it is inherently sequential. You can only parallelize multiple call to this function. In addition you can also call this function from a Numba function (as CPython is slow and calling Numba function from CPython introduces an overhead). GPUs are designed to run massively parallel code so there is no chance to run this on a GPU efficiently since the function is not parallel. Besides, you should read the CUDA Numba documentation carefully as functions need to be modified so to be executed on a GPU properly.

The layout of `b` and its access pattern (`b[i1][0]`) is not very efficient as it prevent the code to be vectorized. Please consider transposing the array so contiguous accesses can be done. If the while loop is short, then the unpredictability prevent any processor to run it efficiently. If the while loop is long, then the current code should be mostly memory bound. If `b` contains sorted numbers, then you can use a galloping search or a binary search.